# Android - Absolute unit of measurement

Tags: android, units-of-measurement

If I wanted to create something that is exactly one inch apart on every Android screen,  I would use pixels correct? Inches and dp seem to scale to the individual size of the screen meaning on one device it could be one inch and on another it could be 1 1/4th.

Also, is there an easier way to do this besides finding how many pixels are in an inch and then adding the views with the correct margin pragmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You would use *density independent* pixels. Also known as *dip* or just *dp*.

*Dp* ensure that things are nearly the same size on every screen. ("Nearly" because this is android, with a huge fragmentation, and custom roms, ...etc)

So one inch will be a varying amount of pixels on each screen. If you use pixels, things will be smaller on high resolution displays. So use *dp* and everything will be the correct size on the actual screens.

While using *dp* might be off by a pixel or two (*might*!), this is probably as good as it gets. Also, you should try not to create pixel perfect design with android—You will have a hard time with different screen sizes (and not just resolutions)
Generally speaking you should try and follow the [material design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) by google for android, and rather use multiples of `8dp` for sizes, instead of trying to find out how much an inch is.

Answer (score 0):

Density-independent pixels (dp) is the unit of measure which appears to be the same actual length on any device.

Try this: create a view whose width is 100dp and run it on a hdpi device. Measure the width of the view using a ruler or something. Then run the app on a mdpi device and measure the width. You will find that the two widths are about the same.

This means that, just as its name suggests, the actual length of a dp is independent of the screen density.

If you used pixels, however, the actual length will vary from screen density to screen density. If the screen is denser, 100px will appear shorter. If the screen is less dense, 100px will appear longer.

Get it?

tl;dr: Just use dp!